# Why do I have this error : Error BC305016

Tags: vba, report, reportbuilder3.0

I'm working on a report on microsoft report builder and on one of the textbox I have this formula

> =iif(Parameters!DescritpionOnOff.Value=0,
> (iif(Parameters!Model.Value not like "",
> "On " + Join(Parameters!Model.Value, ", ") + " version",
> ""
> )),
> (iif(Parameters!DescriptionBody.Value "",
> Fields!Descritpion.Value,
> Parameters!DescriptionBody.Value
> ))
> )

When I launch the report I have the error
*The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox1082.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments.*
I tried to rewrite it, change the brackets but nothing work.
Can someone explain me why this does not work ?

Making a dynamic value based on a filed that let you choose or not if a there is a text, and if this parameter is not activated, there is text that appear in the place of it

Comment: Could it be that there is a typo: `DescritpionOnOff`?

Comment: No it's not that unfortunately, my spelling are correct (I double checked everything, that's a typo i made even in the parameter)

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is too low to write a comment, so I am writing a reply. I hope it helps you a little.

The error BC305016 means that the IIF statement does not have the correct number of arguments.

If I understand it correctly, you want to check two conditions in your IIF statement.  So in ordinary language (pseudo code) the following should be checked:

IF the DescriptionOnOff.Value parameter has the value 0 AND IF the Model.Value parameter does not contain nothing (""), then something (which is unclear to me) should happen.

In general, the correct syntax for checking two (or more) conditions in an IIF statement is as follows:

```
=IIF((Condition1) AND
 (Condition2), THEN, ELSE)
```

However, your expression is structured like this:

```
=IIF(Condition1),
IIF(Condition2), THEN, ELSE)
```

So the second condition is not an AND part, but the THEN part, followed by another THEN part, and that causes the error (*no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments*). In addition, brackets are also not set correctly.

So the first part of your code should look something like this:

```
=IIF((Parameters!DescritpionOnOff.Value=0) AND
(Parameters!Model.Value not like ""), "On ",ELSE)
```

Instead of *not like ""*, the Decision Function *Is Nothing* is probably a better choice. More information about this and about IIF statements can be found in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver16).

The JOIN statement that follows, which I assume is supposed to be the ELSE part, is a separate topic. Here, I suspect, there are also errors in the syntax.